# Map-Reduce in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mapreduce, async.js

I have my `array=[{id:"1"}, {id:"2"}, {id:"3"}]` and want to convert it to object: `{"1":true, "2", true, "3":true};`
 so I have done the following:

```
async.reduce(myArray, {}, function (memo, item, callback) {
    memo[item.id] = true;
    callback(null, memo);
}, function (err, myObj) {
    console.log("converted object", myObj);
}
```

It does the job, however I'm not sure if this makes sense in terms of performance or it is pointless? [Here](https://github.com/caolan/async#reducearr-memo-iterator-callback) they have suggested to use map reduce, but still I'm confused how I can do it with map and reduce to improve the performance; any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So is there anything asyncronous going on inside this reduce, or in other words, you're iterating over something that is used in an asynchronous operation, right? Otherwise it makes no sense at all!

Comment: Using `async` is entirely pointless if you're doing a synchronous operation. It'll only slow you down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, there is nothing asynchronous in your `reduce` function, so you are better using the regular `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
var array = [{id:"1"}, {id:"2"}, {id:"3"}];
var newArray = array.reduce(function(cur, val) {
    cur[val.id] = true;
    return cur;
}, {});

console.log(newArray);
// => { '1': true, '2': true, '3': true }
```

Comment: your comparison is not right; this is not the right usage of async.reduce; async.reduce is used when you have callbacks and the nature of calls are async!It is obvious in your example Array.prototype.reduce is getting better performance result because your operation inside async.reduce is not asynchronous!

Comment: Yes, I thought there was something weird on that comparison. Anyway, I rolled back that edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1 - Synchronous Reduce (closest to code given)

While the `reduce` function of the `async` library is useful, it's only necessary when the reduce operation preforms an asynchronous action (one with a callback). For simple and synchronous tasks, the native Javascript `Array.reduce` method will suffice.

```
// given myArray like [{id:"1"}, {id:"2"}, {id:"3"}]

var newObject = myArray.reduce(function(obj, current){
    obj[current.id] = true;
    return obj;
}, {}); // { '1': true, '2': true,'3': true }
```

#### Method 2 - `Array.forEach`

By creating an empty object, then looping through the array and adding to it, this method will produce the same result.

```
// given myArray like [{id:"1"}, {id:"2"}, {id:"3"}]

var newObject = {};

myArray.forEach(function(element){
    newObject[element.id] = true;
});

// newDictionary is now { '1': true, '2': true,'3': true }
```

#### Method 2½ - Array Instead of Object

If all of your keys (`id`s) for the object are integers, you might consider using an array instead of a object.

Method 1 with Array:
`[{}].concat(myArray)` would become `[[]].concat(myArray)`

Method 2 with Array:
`}, {});` would change to `}, []);`

Good luck!

Comment: No, you don't want to prepend an object. You want to feed it as the second parameter to `reduce`!!!

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the feedback. answer has been updated to reflect this. (I would say that while prepending it is *definitely* not elegant nor efficient, it would function fine)

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to make asyncs calls also if it might be a potentially large array and the standard JavaScript Array.prototype.reduce loop would take too long, making the server hanging (not able to answer requests while doing that loop).

The async operation will take longer than Array.prototype.reduce, forEach or map, but it pays of since the server can answer requests before finishing it (between steps).

Also you can use the async's callback to get each step's partial computation.

If the array will never be that large and you don't need partial results you should just stick to the standard array's synchronous methods.